# Read multiple json files from a directory and parse it using Pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Below script is able to parse single json file but not sure how to implement it for multiple json files from a directory.

My requirement is to read all txt files from the directory: - `json_file="/home/input/*.txt"` and parse it in pyspark. Currently i am able to read single text file `"sample1.txt"` but unable to handle multiple files. When i run below script for multiple files , it throws below error:

**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/input/*.txt'**

Could someone please provide solution to handle multiple Json files from a directory preferably using pyspark data frame as below:

```
spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("Curate_Job_configuration"). \
                           getOrCreate() 


df=spark.read.format("json"). \
    option("inferSchema","true"). \
    option("multiline","true"). \
    load("/home/input/\*.json")
```

Rest all files are nested and having same column name.

```
import json
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

#json_file = "sample1.txt"
json_file="/home/input/*.txt"
def append_item(outlist, item, prefix=''):
    if isinstance(item, (str,int)) or item is None:
        outlist.append((prefix,str(item)))

def curate(outlist, item, level=1, prefix=''):
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        for k, (subkey, subitem) in enumerate(item.items(),1):
            new_prefix = prefix+f"_{subkey}"
            append_item(outlist, subitem, prefix=new_prefix)
            curate(outlist, subitem, level=level+1, prefix=new_prefix)
    elif isinstance(item, list):
        for k, subitem in enumerate(item):
            new_prefix = prefix+f"_{k}"
            curate(outlist, subitem, level=level+1, prefix=new_prefix)
            append_item(outlist, subitem, prefix=new_prefix)
    elif isinstance(item, (str,int)) or item is None:
        append_item(outlist, item, prefix=prefix)
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Unknown item {item} type={type(item)}.")
    return outlist


with open(json_file, 'r') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)

data = []
for j, (key, item) in enumerate(json_data.items(), 1):
    data = curate(data, item, prefix=key)

sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

data_dict = [{col: datum for col, datum in data}]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data_dict)
df.show()
```

Comment: What is the issue you're facing? I've used path-till-directory or '*' wildcard and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks Ronak for your note. Script fails when i use json_file="/home/input/*.txt" in above script to read multiple files. Throws below error :- FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/input/*.txt'

Comment: Cool, can you try "/home/input/*txt" and "/home/input/" as path as well?

Comment: Would appreciate it if could please elaborate it ..I am already passing path in above script :- json_file="/home/input/*.txt" .

Comment: Try with these paths given in the above comments, they've worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this

```
df=spark.read.format("csv").("header","True").load("file:////home/input/*.txt")

json_file="file:///home/input/*.txt"
```

because of the load need details show we use here describe this is file.
revert me any problem, hope it will work